# PowerShell Failed to parse string as JSON

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to run an Azure CLI Command to restore Diagnostics settings for a Firewall and I get the error: `Failed to parse string as JSON`

Loading the segment of Json from an object:

`$metrics = ($fwDiagnostics.metrics) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`

Yields:

`{"category":"AllMetrics","enabled":true,"retentionPolicy":{"days":90,"enabled":false},"timeGrain":null}`

Which looks fine.

But when I run the following command:

`az monitor diagnostic-settings create --name $fwDiagnostics.name --metrics $metrics --workspace $fwDiagnostics.workspaceId --resource $resource.id`

I get:

`Failed to parse string as JSON: {category:AllMetrics,enabled:true,retentionPolicy:{days:90,enabled:false},timeGrain:null} Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Which appears to have stripped out any `""` around the text elements

Comment: Use an Online JSON checker to validate the JSON.  Here is one of many : https://jsonlint.com/?force_isolation=true

Comment: The Json is valid and was created by another Azure CLI command to backup the diagnostics. Trying your link confirmed valid Json, so it is not that

Comment: The sad reality up to PowerShell 7.2.x is that an _extra, manual_ layer of ``\``-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to _external programs_. This has been fixed in PowerShell 7.3,0 with selective exceptions on Windows, for now _by default_ - though a future version may revert to the old, broken behavior, requiring an _opt-in_ for the fix. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: I used `$var.replace('"', '"""')` in the end which one of the answers alluded to. Many thanks